# Ошибка: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

С сервера приходит сообщение в таком формате:

```
String strginDate = "Fri, 05 Jan 2018 15:19:14 GMT";
GMTToDDMMMYYYY(String strginDate)
```

Так вот, я парсю это таким образом:

```
private String GMTToDDMMMYYYY(String gmt){
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd mmm yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = sdf.parse(gmt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String dateStr = simpleDateFormat.format(d);
    return dateStr;
}
```

И получаю ошибку:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 05 Jan 2018 15:19:14
>   GMT" (at offset 0)

Но я перепробовал все, например так:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
```

или

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
```

и даже так:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'");
```

Но результат такой же.

Где я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Нашел ответ, проблема было в том, что нужно было добавить Locale. Я писал Local.getDefault(), а оказывается надо было Locale.US

Comment: Оформите найденное решение как ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ, проблема было в том, что нужно было добавить `Locale`.

Я писал `Local.getDefault()`, а оказывается надо было `Locale.US`

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.US);
```